# Does this easier method to find the invariant lines of a transformation always work?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-theory

In class, I was learning about finding the invariant lines of a linear transformation. For example this question:

> Find the invariant lines of the transformation $\begin{pmatrix} 5&1\\2&4 \end{pmatrix}$.

I was taught by my teacher this method:

Let $(x, y)$ be a point that gets mapped to the point $(x', y')$.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5&1 \\
2&4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x' \\
y'
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using matrix multiplication,

$$
x'=5x+y\\
y'=2x+4y
$$

Then I substitute these expressions into the general equation of a line ($y=mx+c$):

$$
2x+4y=m(5x+y)+c
$$

Rearranging into the form $y=mx+c$

$$
y=\frac{5m-2}{4-m}x+\frac{c}{4-m}
$$

---

Up to this point, me and my friend's methods are the same. I would continue by substituting $y=mx+c$ into the above equation and after a whole ton of rearranging, I would get this:

$$
x(m-1)(m+2)=4c-mc
$$

And I would reason that $4c-mc$ won't change no matter what value of $x$ is. Therefore $(m-1)(m+2)$ must be 0 and $m=1$ or $m=-2$. And using the fact that $4c-mc$ is also 0, we can easily find $c=0$, hence finding the 2 invariant lines.

---

My friend found another easier way though. He notices that this line:

$$
y=\frac{5m-2}{4-m}x+\frac{c}{4-m}
$$

has the same gradient as $m$, so

$$
\frac{5m-2}{4-m}=m
$$

We can then easily solve for $m$. Then substitute the values back into $mx+c=\frac{5m-2}{4-m}x+\frac{c}{4-m}$, getting $c=0$.

My question is, does my friend's method give the same answers as my method for all matrices? If not, for what kind of matrix will it give the same answers?

Comment: Neither of these methods will find vertical invariant lines—there’s no value of $m$ that can represent them in the form $y=mx+c$. Moral: that form of equation of a line isn’t _really_ “general.”

Comment: @amd yes I am aware of that. I guess I should change my question to “is my friend’s method as good as mine?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are equivalent. Your friend is equating the coefficients of two equal polynomials: if $Ax+B=Cx+D$ for *all* values of $x$, then $A=C$ and $B=D$. This sets up a system of two equations in $m$ and $c$, which he then proceeds to solve by back-substitution. You’re solving the same system of equations via a different route: what you’re doing amounts to subtracting one equation of the line from the other and then rearranging.